# What two values occur most commonly per category?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns: ID number, category, and brand:

```
X1             X2               X3
1234           Accessories     A89
1234           Accessories     A87
1234           Accessories     A87
1234           Sides           A32
1234           Sides           A27
1234           Sides           A27
1235           Tops            A12
1235           Tops            A14
1235           Tops            A14
1236           Sides           A32
1236           Sides           A27
```

I have 150 different categories and 1700 different brands.

I want to find the two brands per category bought together most often:

```
  X2             X1
Accessories       A89, A87
Sides             A32, A27
Tops              A12, A14
```

or:

```
#$Accessories
    #[1] "A89" "A87"

#$Sides
    #[1] "A32" "A27"

#$Tops
    #[1] "A12" "A14"
```

The only way I could think of was to rework the data frame to look like this:

```
     A89   A87   A32   A27   A12   A14  
1    1     2     1     2     0     0
2    0     0     0     0     1     2
3    0     0     1     1     0     0
```

And then return the columns that are populated with values greater than 0 when a certain column is populated with values greater than 0.

```
list1 =(setNames(object = lapply(1:NCOL(df), function(i)
  unique(colnames(df)[-i][which(as.matrix(df[which(df[,i] > 0), -i])>0,
                                       arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]])),
  nm = colnames(df)))
```

but then I sacrifice the category, which I need. 
Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'X2', 'X3', we get the number of rows (`.N`), then grouped by 'X2' and `order` by the `factor` converted 'X3' and the 'N', we get the `unique` values of 'X3' and `paste` the first two elements.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .N, .(X2, X3)][order(factor(X3, levels = unique(X3)), -N),
       .(X1 = toString(unique(X3)[1:2])) , X2]
#            X2       X1
#1: Accessories A89, A87
#2:       Sides A32, A27
#3:        Tops A12, A14
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 
 1234L, 1235L, 1235L, 1235L, 1236L, 1236L), X2 = c("Accessories", 
 "Accessories", "Accessories", "Accessories", "Sides", "Sides", 
 "Sides", "Tops", "Tops", "Tops", "Sides", "Sides"), X3 = c("A89", 
 "A87", "A87", "A02", "A32", "A27", "A27", "A12", "A14", "A14", 
 "A32", "A27")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```